# Change (rather than Uninstall) an Install4j application

Tags: install4j

What I believe to be a common occurrence is for Install4j to be used to generate both an installer as well as an uninstaller. From what I've seen, the installer can be used to reinstall/reconfigure the installed application.

On Microsoft Windows, the uninstaller gets registered under the `Programs and Features > Uninstall or change a program` item in the Control Panel. Is it possible for that uninstaller to be used to 'change' the installed application, rather than uninstall it? For some users of Windows, this might seem more natural than running the installer again, I suspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 10.0, install4j does not offer such a feature. You can add additional installer applications to run additional actions, but the "Install files" action can only be run in the installer.